# Inner aggregation get latest date on an array level

Tags: elasticsearch

Been trying to write a difficult query, and it's getting the better of me.

Say I have 3 docs like these:

```
Doc #1:
{
  "database_backups" : [
    {
      "Date" : "2021-09-03",
      "Name" : "EventsAPI",
      "Type" : "Full"
    },
    {
      "Date" : "2021-09-04",
      "Name" : "EventsAPI",
      "Type" : "Diff"
    },
    {
      "Date" : "2021-09-05",
      "Name" : "EventsAPI",
      "Type" : "Log"
    }
  ]
}
Doc #2:
{
  "database_backups" : [
    {
      "Date" : "2021-09-01",
      "Name" : "EventsAPI",
      "Type" : "Full"
    }
  ]
}
Doc #3:
{
  "database_backups" : [
    {
      "Date" : "2021-09-02",
      "Name" : "EventsAPI",
      "Type" : "Diff"
    },
    {
      "Date" : "2021-09-01",
      "Name" : "EventsSecurity",
      "Type" : "Diff"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get latest backups of each unique Name + Type. So i would need Name+Type+Date as a result.

I've tried composite agg to link Name + Type, and that worked.

However, when I also try to add max agg on Date, it selects the max Date of the entire doc, rather than a specific object that fits Name + Type in the array.

So for example EventsAPI + Diff agg's max Date would be "2021-09-05", because that's a max Date in Doc#1, but it's a date for EventsAPI + Log, rather than EventsAPI + Diff.

Is it possible to get the latest date of the Name + Type key for that particular object in the array?

The result I'm looking for should give this info somehow:

```
EventsSecurity + Diff + "2021-09-01"
EventsAPI + Full + "2021-09-03"
EventsAPI + Diff + "2021-09-04"
EventsAPI + Log  + "2021-09-05"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database_backups needs to be of type nested to maintain relation ship between inner object fields.

terms aggregation can  be used to get max date for each event and type

**Query**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "database_backups"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "database_backups.Name.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "database_backups.Type.keyword",
                "size": 10
              },
              "aggs": {
                "NAME": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "database_backups.Date"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count" : 6,
      "NAME" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "EventsAPI",
            "doc_count" : 5,
            "NAME" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "Diff",
                  "doc_count" : 2,
                  "NAME" : {
                    "value" : 1.6307136E12,
                    "value_as_string" : "2021-09-04T00:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "key" : "Full",
                  "doc_count" : 2,
                  "NAME" : {
                    "value" : 1.6306272E12,
                    "value_as_string" : "2021-09-03T00:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "key" : "Log",
                  "doc_count" : 1,
                  "NAME" : {
                    "value" : 1.6308E12,
                    "value_as_string" : "2021-09-05T00:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "EventsSecurity",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "NAME" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "Diff",
                  "doc_count" : 1,
                  "NAME" : {
                    "value" : 1.6304544E12,
                    "value_as_string" : "2021-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```